Products of the Householder matrices during QR decomposition
It is often said that there is no need to form the Householder matrix during QR decomposition, however I fail to see how to "manage" the product of $n$ Householder matrixes and the matrix $A$, i.e.
where
$$
H_n A = R \;\;\;\text{where} \;\;\;H_n = \prod_{i = 1}^n \left(I - \beta_i v_iv_i^T\right)
$$
For example if $n = 3$
$$
\left(I - \beta_3 v_3v_3^T\right)
\left(I - \beta_2 v_2v_2^T\right)
\left(I - \beta_1 v_1v_1^T\right)
A
$$
The best I've come up with is:
$$
(I - \beta_1 v_1v_1^T - \beta_2 v_2v_2^T - \beta_3 v_3v_3^T + \beta_1 \beta_2 v_1v_1^Tv_2v_2^T + \beta_1 \beta_3 v_1v_1^Tv_3v_3^T + \beta_2 \beta_3 v_2v_2^Tv_3v_3^T )A
$$
Obviously, the $v_iv_j^T$'s become constants but this barely makes the problem tractable especially when $n$ is arbitrarily large.
Or is there another way to efficiently compute these products? I am interested in computing $Q = H^T$ and $R$.
If it matters the matrix $A$ is block tridiagonal.

LAPACK documentation contains some nice references for working with these matrices: https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node69.html

Work through that product from right to left, overwriting A as you go. Each overwrite is a rank-1 outer product update. This procedure (backwards accumulation) applies H^T, leaving R within A.

@rchilton1980 Thanks. Because I need $Q$ as well wouldn't make sense to first multiply the Householder matrices (alone) from the right, before multiplying the result, $Q^T$, by $A$?

Often the action of Q or Q^T is enough? There's some mild caution in actually forming it, because it takes more memory to tabulate Q into a dense matrix than to store the generating vectors (v). If you're using LAPACK for this, you can drill into the QR routines dgeqrf, dormqr and dorgqr for help with these tasks. It implements all these algorithms (factor, apply Q, tabulate Q) and will help you figure out the right strategy.

You are right. I am transforming $Ax = b$ to $QRx = b$ which implies $Rx = Q^Tb$ so yes the action of $Q^T$ on $A$ and $b$ are sufficient.

@rchilton1980 What I find confusing about this scheme is that, as I understand it, the process of calculating the Householder vectors $v$ creates $R$, so why multiply $H$ to $A$??

You compute recursively as follows:
$$
A_1 := (I-\beta_1 v_1 v_1^T)A = A - \beta_1 v_1 (v_1^TA);
$$
$$
A_2 := (I-\beta_2 v_2 v_2^T)A_1 = A_1 - \beta_2 v_2 (v_2^TA_1);
$$
$$
A_3 := (I-\beta_3 v_3 v_3^T)A_2 = A_2 - \beta_3 v_3 (v_3^TA_2).
$$
The right-hand side in each line gives formulas to compute
$$
A_3 = (I-\beta_3 v_3 v_3^T)(I-\beta_2 v_2 v_2^T)(I-\beta_1 v_1 v_1^T)A$$
in $O(numel(A))$.

Isn't the Householder vector $v_3$ the third column of the product of $H_2 H_1 A$, i.e $\left(I - \beta_1 v_1v_1^T\right)\left(I - \beta_2 v_2v_2^T\right)A$

Correction I've just realized that the order of the matrix multiplication is $\left(I - \beta_3 v_3v_3^T\right)
\left(I - \beta_2 v_2v_2^T\right)
\left(I - \beta_1 v_1v_1^T\right)
A$

Same idea, only the order of the indices change. But you are correct, that is the order that one typically needs in QR factorization.
